# Removing particular content from result parces using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
def get_description(link):
    redditFile = urllib2.urlopen(link)
    redditHtml = redditFile.read()
    redditFile.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(redditHtml)
    desc = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'op_gd14 FL'}).text
    return desc
```

This is the code which gives me text from this html

```
    <div class="op_gd14 FL">
    <p><span class="bigT">P</span>restige Estates Projects Ltd has informed BSE that the 18th Annual General Meeting (AGM) of the Company will be held on September 30, 2015.Source : BSE<br><br>  
<a href="../../company-notices/nestleindia/notices/PEP02">Read all announcements in Prestige Estate</a>  </p><p>                                                </p>

</div>
```

This result is fine for me, I just want to exclude the content of

`<a href="../../company-notices/nestleindia/notices/PEP02">Read all announcements in Prestige Estate</a>`

from result, that is `desc` in my script, if it is present and Ignore if it is not present. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`extract()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Removing%20elements) to remove unnecessary tags from the `find()` result:

```
descItem = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'op_gd14 FL'}) # get the DIV
[s.extract() for s in descItem('a')]                       # remove <a> tags
return descItem.get_text()                                 # return the text
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make some changes to last line and add re module

```
...
return re.sub(r'<a(.*)</a>','',desc)
```

Output:

```
'<div class="op_gd14 FL">\n    <p><span class="bigT">P</span>restige Estates Projects Ltd has informed BSE that the 18th Annual General Meeting (AGM) of the Company will be held on September 30, 2015.Source : BSE<br><br>  \n  </p><p>
```

Comment: thanks, but still it need change I guess, because, there would not be `<a></a>` in `desc`

Comment: No changes needed if r'<a(.*)</a>' == False it just passes as it is

Comment: no, because `desc` will not contains html. its only text content